# How can I launch my PyCharm faster?

Tags: python, pycharm, launch

My notebook is bought at 2010, CPU is  i5-2410M, RAM 8G. But at each time I launch my PyCharm, it will take me about 5 minutes or more.
How can I improve my launch of PyCharm, if i use the same notebook? Is there any better launch strategy for PyCharm?

Comment: you should mention your os. also as a tag

Comment: How is this a duplicate? The question is how to make it lauch it faster not how to make it run faster. I have the same problem with my Ubuntu 18.04, hope there was a good answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

This looks to have been answered before and may help you.

[pycharm running wayyyy slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363526/pycharm-running-wayyyy-slow)

(Taken from above)

**1. Change the inspection level**

Current PyCharm versions allows you to change the type of static code analysis it performs, and also features a Power/CPU Saving feature (Click on the icon at the bottom right, next to the lock):

**2. Change indexed directories**

Exclude directories from being indexed which are set in the project paths but not actually required to be searched and indexed. Press ALT+CTRL+S and search for project.

**3. Do memory sweeps**

There is another interesting feature:

Go into the settings (File/Settings) and search for memory. In IDE Settings>Appearance -> tick Show memory indicator. A memory bar will be shown at the bottom right corner (see the picture below). Click this bar to run a garbage collection / memory sweep.

If you monitor the startup of the app through task manager, is there any noticeable jump in CPU/Memory usage that might indicate its a resource problem?

I'm not too familiar with this IDE, but normally its either something in the application causing slow startup that can be stopped through the options, or alternatively, machine resources being lackluster at time of startup.