# PyCharm: Python's standard lib's names and functions are underlined as "No module named such"

Tags: pycharm

**Context**

- I am using PyCharm Version 2016.1.1
- This is an Editor display format (almost aesthetic) question, I have configured pycharm's interpreter correctly, and my codes can run no problem.

**The question:**

PyCharm has this nice feature of underlining syntaxes, if you invoke a function that does not exist in a module, pycharm underline that function. My problem is that, my pycharm is underlining all standard python modules and functions with a red wiggly line. And when you mouse over the wiggly line, a context tips appears saying "no module named `module`". for example `print()` `super()` gets underlined, all imports like `sys` `tkinter` get underlined.

My code runs fine no problem, my interpreter is "3.5.1(C:\Anaconda3\python.exe)".

Comment: I think SO has a very power ability here, while I can not always search for answers in SO effectively with a mere title or key phrases, but when I typed out the whole question and post it, it does link me to relevant posts. in the post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363526/pycharm-running-wayyyy-slow?rq=1) **pycharm running wayyy slow**  the author mentioned similar problem in an older version and the author mentioned his solution. I tried the solution, did not work at the beginning, but after an hour, it worked, because pycharm was refreshing index slowly in the background.

Comment: it is an obscure question, if no one has better idea I will just type up the solution in my above comment. so people can search for it in the future

Comment: what tooltip do you see when you hover over the items?

Comment: Exactly is "no module named print" or "no module named tkinter". But very good reminder, I should reword my question a bit