# Pycharm specify needed modules for indexing instead of my whole python packages?

Tags: python, pycharm

By time, I am installing more and more python modules and my site packages directory has been huge. So each time I open pycharm I have to wait about 15 minutes (or MORE) for indexing to finish. So my question is: how can I sort of specify the modules I need for my project only to get indexed instead of indexing my whole python installation ?

Comment: Tried to exclude the folder?

Comment: The solution for this is keeping your virtual environments clean with only the packages necessary for one given project. Whatever environments/interpreters you specify in 1 PyCharm project will be indexed.

Comment: Here's [one thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29030682) among [several](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bpycharm%5d%20indexing) dealing with this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pycharm running way slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363526/pycharm-running-way-slow)

Answer (score 0):

You can't. I think you should split the project in smaller units.

Comment: What do you mean ? Please clarify

Comment: Not doing everything in one interpreter would be the simplest solution

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an PyCharm issue.
I recommend one of the following:

- Update the PyCharm as there are bugs found in the indexing in older versions
- Use a different editor like VScode
- Or use virtual environments like anaconda (although this does cost some disk space)